# entity framework 7 for visual studio code editor

Tags: entity-framework

I want to add the entity framework 7 to my asp.net core application in visual studio code editor. Can I add this using command prompt. If can anyone provide commands. Orelse Is there any other ways to do it??

Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: did my answer solved your problem or you need more info how can load the assemblies etc?

Comment: yes, i need update my project.json right?..and also i need to know how to load assemblies

Comment: dotnet restore  --->This command will load the assmblies to your project <------ here you have an example for a project.json https://readthedocs.com/projects/aspnet-ef/downloads/pdf/latest/

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio Code is an editor and not Visual Studio IDE as you know it, It doesn't install any packages.You have to install them manually.

Here is an tutorial:

https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html

You can install the C# extension from the VS Code Marketplace:

```
ext install csharp
```

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp

---

**Installing Entity Framework for .Net Core**

In *.NET Core* just add the project.json(with all required references) to your project and then call:

```
dotnet restore
```

**Installing EntityFramwork for .Net Full(4.X)**

You need Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
```